# Unity3D: Build not working for Hololens (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, build, hololens

I am developing an application for Hololens through Unity3D. When I run my Unity3d application on Editor, it works fine.

But when I try to build it on Universal Windows Platform, it gives me this error

```
    Failed to find a placeholder ('Assets/JsonDotNet/Assemblies/Standalone

/Newtonsoft.Json.dll') for 'Assets/IBMSdkCore/ThirdParty/JsonDotNet

/AOT/Newtonsoft.Json.dll', ensure it exists, or change plugin settings for

 'Assets/IBMSdkCore/ThirdParty/JsonDotNet/AOT/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' accordingly.
```

I am not sure why? When I build it on Windows Standalone, it generates an exe file. Not sure why it doesnt work only for UWP?

Comment: If Newtonsoft.Json.dll exists in your Assets folder, the [Unity Plugin Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html) may be able to help troubleshoot whether or not it is declared useable by UWP builds. It might be that some flavors of Newtonsoft.Json.dll exist that work in the editor (The editor uses Standalone x86_x64 dlls) that aren't declared as useable for UWP (WSA Player x86/arm/x64).

Comment: You may also need to put these dlls in a [Unity special folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) (Plugins\WSA\x86, Plugins\WSA\arm, Plugins\WSA\x64, etc) for them to get picked up correctly in your build.

Comment: @chrisfromwork Thank you so much! It worked!